# Dto information not displayed

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

I use spring boot 3

implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.0.4'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.4'
implementation project(':common')

In my SwaggerConfig file

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi groupAcmeApi() {

    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("Acme")
            .pathsToMatch("/person/**", "/child/**")
            .packagesToScan("com.acme.lcm.person.controller", "com.acme.common.child.dto")
            .build();
}
```

Actually, swagger don't display information who come from of my commonn project

```
public class Person {
    @Schema(description = "Id person", type = "Long")
    private Long id;
    ...

    @Schema(description = "Child", type = "Object")
    private ChildDto child;

}

public class ChildDto {

    @Schema(description = "Child id", type = "Long")
    private Long childId;

    @Schema(description = "Name of the shild", type = "String")
    private String name;
    ....
}
```

Field of ChildDto is not displayed in swagger